# Problems using cv::dnn::Layer cv::dnn::LayerFactory and cv::dnn::Net

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm a beginner with opencv. I have recently taken part in a winter camp about computer science.From there I have learnt about some knowledge about machine learning using Pytorch.However, I know nothing about python. I'm trying to build my deep neural network by using the dnn header files in opencv2/dnn using VS with C++.But I failed, and there's barely any examples on using cv::dnn::Net, cv::dnn::Layer and cv::dnn::LayerFactory, I really need a brief demo to help me.

Comment: It takes a long time to learn C++. Really it would be more efficient if you started with something simpler and when you've got a good grounding go back to your deep neural networks.

Comment: I'm quite agree with you.I have learnt C++ for 3 years,and I can't say that "I'm the master of C++".But I can say that I know about C++ :P.Now the problem is that when using some 3rd party libraries the documents seem to be not that helpful(especially when i searched for details in official opencv documents).It's really difficult for learners like me to use these libraries.

Comment: Lee8950, Deep learning networks are not just built. You need to train it with for a specific task using tons of images data. So before you can work with deep learning model you need to 1) collect data 2) label data 3) choose one of frameworks (TensorFlow/PyTorch/Caffe etc.) and train a network with it 4) Use OpenCV for model deployment. Comparing with training frameworks OpenCV is more efficient however before using it you need to have a trained network.